# How to extend Auth object in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a default table users and related table `user_details.`

When user does auth it retrieves data from users table and is available to global object:

```
Auth::user()
```

How to extend Auth::user() with data from related table `user_details`?

Reason is to show a full information about authenticated user in each pages(at header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, don't need to extend Auth, just your User model. You can us a couple of different helpers, ->hasOne, ->belongsTo, etc on your User model (assuming you have a user_details model) and eloquent should do the rest.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

EDIT:
You can add an accessor to your user model.
SO, in your app\User.php

```
public function getCustomAttribute()
{
    return 'Custom Attribute';
}
```

You should be able to get that anywhere with something like

```
Auth::user()->custom
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators

(again, it is possible that I am just not understanding your question)

Comment: I have 30 controllers, I dont want to write the same code in each like this. I need to fill Auth object once and use this throughout all application

Comment: Yes, I have relations one to one in model `User`: `public function doctor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Doctor', 'user_id', 'id');
    }`. But if to do the following `{{dd(Auth::user())}}` There is not relation `doctor` in object